# How to read different types of segments from input file in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

sample data arriving in input file:
Sample data comprises three segments - BS - Borrower, RS - Relationship, CR - Credit Facility (Trade Line). How to read this data which has separate layout and parse using spark.

Layout Definition of the segments

```
BS - Borrower: Indicator, First name, Last, name, Company name, joining date
RS - Relationship: Indicator, Name, Role, Company Name
CR - Credity facility: Indicator, Type of Loan, Account Number, Sanctioned date, Amount
```

Sample data:

```
BS,Rohan,Mundle,Infy,20230101
RS,Sohan Mundle,Director,Croma
CR,Home Loan, 10023045, 20200101, 10000.00
BS,Priyatee,Sinha,L&T,20220101
RS,Mohan Mehta,Owner, ABC Tech
CR,Home Loan, 20023045, 20200301, 50000.00
```

How to read the data mentioned above with type safe method in spark scala.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract multi-line record from a text file with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901732/how-can-i-extract-multi-line-record-from-a-text-file-with-spark)

Answer (score 0):

Three different dataframes can be extracted from one text file, by reading data in `Dataset[String]` and filtering data by indicator, with assigning right schema:

```
val mixedData: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile("sampleData.csv")

def readWithSchema(indicator: String, schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
  val segmentData = mixedData.filter(_.startsWith(indicator))
  spark.read.schema(schema).csv(segmentData)
}

val borrowerSchema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField(name = "Indicator", dataType = StringType),
    StructField(name = "First name", dataType = StringType),
    StructField(name = "Last name", dataType = StringType),
    StructField(name = " Company name", dataType = StringType),
    StructField(name = " joining date", dataType = StringType)
  )
)
val borrowers = readWithSchema("BS", borrowerSchema)
// Declare schema for `Relationship` and `Credity facility`, and read with `readWithSchema`
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|Indicator|First name|Last name| Company name| joining date|
+---------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
|BS       |Rohan     |Mundle   |Infy         |20230101     |
|BS       |Priyatee  |Sinha    |L&T          |20220101     |
+---------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+
```